# Dealing with high resolution images

Tags: android, css, cordova

I'm in the process of developing a simple iphone/android web app using phonegap and I'm having difficulty providing high resolution images for newer android devices. I'm assuming that I can use the same ones I created for the iphone 4. These are kept in a separate css file and are controlled by the media query below:

```
media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)"
```

Inside are a bunch of css rules like:

```
.homepage-list li.about { background-image: url(../images/info@2x.png); -webkit-background-size: 35px 35px; }
```

Both the android emulator and a real android device (HTC Desire HD) just won't display those images but an iphone 4 does. Oddly enough, if I modify the above rule and add a border then that border is shown. So the media query is being understood as far as I can tell.

I'm a bit stumped for ideas. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the folder structure of your application? i.e. where is the www directory, and the index.html, and your images folder, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to display other images in the same folder?

Try to rename the image and don't include any "strange" characters like @

Comment: yeah i can display all the low res images (ones that dont have @2x at the end). i'll try removing the @ characters and see what happens.